# Php getIsoWeeks for a long time

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have the following scenario:

- calender with employees swapping each week their shift. 3 possible shifts.

With a simple calculation of the isoWeek in the year I calculate the index of the shifts, the array of the shifts looks simply like this: `{3, 2, 1}` or `{2, 1, 3}` and so on.

**This is my loop:**

```
$year = 2018;
$weeksOfYear = getIsoWeeksInYear($year); //Returns either 52 or 53

$shiftData = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= $weeksOfYear; $i++) {
    $shiftIndex = getIndexShift($i);
```

**This is the calculation:**

```
function getIndexShift($week){
    $helper = floor((($week/3) - floor($week/3))*100)/100;
    switch ($helper) {
        case 0:
            return 2;
        case 0.66:
            return 1;
        case 0.33:
            return 0;
    }
    return "error";
}
```

Works like a charm, my problem is that on a new year it fails. Week 52 returns 0,33 which means index 0. Week 1 of the next year also, so we have twice the same shift. If the year has 53 weeks, it returns 0,66 so 1 which would be fine.

So this is the actual situation, I try to find now a way to get it working long term. The first thing that came in my mind is to do it some kind of this:

`isoWeeks since 1980 until the year variable + my current loop (loops from 1 to 52/53 Weeks based on the provided year)`

So I have an ongoing number and it would work.

Any idea how to achieve this ? Or a different approach ? 
I tried yet to loop since 1980 trough every year, calculate the weeks of the year and count them together until 2018. Works but seems just way to much.

**Edit Thanks to unherz, I shortened the calculation to:**

```
function getIndexShift($week){
    return $week % 3; //Returns 0 or 1, 2 Perfectly. 
}
```

Comment: Personally I would recommend to use the modulo-operator:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php
(ist the "%"-char). I often sue this to avoid mathematical-logical problems

Comment: Please also look up the DateTime-Object in PHP: http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php
It is also possbile to solve your problem using this :)

Comment: @unherz Oh I will definetly look in the modulo operator, ty for that. With datetime I already tried arround but couldn´t get the isoWeeks for a long period just for a specific year, date, month.